# The mechanism behind Unity3D visual programming third party tools

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First sorry for posting this here.I just got no answer to this question on "Unity Answers"I have been looking into the tools like [uScript](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/84594-Introducing-the-uScript-Visual-Scripting-Tool-for-Unity!) or [Strumpy Shader](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/56180-Strumpy-Shader-Editor-4.0a-Massive-Improvements) Editors which are node based visual programming tools like Unreal Kismet or 3DsMax particle flow system. I have been researching on how in fact these tools generate the source code in Unity.So I assume that during the node logic assembly the code should be generated and compiled to DLLs (in Unity all the source code is compiled into DLLs)dynamically.I started looking into such C# assemblies like Reflections , Microsoft.CSharp and System.CodeDom.Compiler; I even tried to write a C# class in Unity via the editor as a text and then parse and compile it into DLL using the above mentioned tools(it was ok but the DLL was existing only during the Runtime in the temp..) Therefore I would like to know is this the approach those tools are likely to use? Or there is a better and cleaner way to do it ?Thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm actually in the process of doing the same thing.. I think you are on the right path with the Compiler classes. I dont think you can emit IL on the fly on mobile devices as a security sandbox issue but I'm dynamically creating c# code and compiling it into persistent dll's like this..

```
CompilerParameters compilerParameter = new CompilerParameters();
compilerParameter.OutputAssembly = "/Your/Path/Here.dll";
CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
code.AppendLine("public static class Test {");
//More code here...
code.AppendLine("}");
var compilerResult = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameter, code.ToString());
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Does this assembly continue to exist after you exit the app? In my case it was temporal.

Comment: I'm using this code to generate a persistent .dll from an EditorApplication inside Unity. The .dll that's created is permanent and can be published with the final application. If you use a relative path for the OutputAssembly like "Assets/MyDLL.dll" you will see it after you run the compiler located in your project. Move it to Assets/DLL and you can use it.